# How to populate faster in datagridview in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, performance, datagridview

This is my code for populating the datagridview:

```
Public Sub generate_list_ftMK(ByVal clbBranch As CheckedListBox, ByVal dtpSDate As DateTimePicker, ByVal dtpEDate As DateTimePicker, ByVal dvList As DataGridView)
    Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()
    Dim da As MySqlDataAdapter


    Dim strQ As String = String.Empty
    Dim strQ1 As String = String.Empty


    Dim colItemCode As String = String.Empty
    Dim colReg_Pri As String = String.Empty
    Dim colXL_Pri As String = String.Empty
    Dim colDel_Date As String = String.Empty
    Dim colLabel As String = String.Empty
    Dim colDays As String = String.Empty
    Dim PCT As String = String.Empty

    Try
        If con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then con.Close()
        con.Open()

        'clear the dataset
        ds.Tables.Clear()

        'loop for all branches
        For i = 0 To clbBranch.CheckedItems.Count - 1

            Application.DoEvents()

            'get the Branch Code
            chkBranch = clbBranch.CheckedItems(i).ToString

            'select item code and price where JO_TYPE is JO
            strQ = "select " & _
                     "CONCAT(a.STYLE_CODE, '-', LPAD((a.JO_NO), 4, '0'), '-', d.LINE_NO) as Item_Code, " & _
                        "DATE_FORMAT(c.DEL_DATE, '%Y-%m-%d') as DEL_DATE, " & _
                        "d.REG_PRI as Reg_Price, " & _
                        "d.XL_PRI as XL_Price, " & _
                        "a.LABEL_CODE, " & _
                        "a.STYLE_CODE, " & _
                        "LPAD((a.JO_NO), 4, '0')," & _
                        "d.LINE_NO, " & _
                        "DATEDIFF('" & Format(Date.Now, "yyyy-MM-dd") & "',DATE_FORMAT(c.DEL_DATE, '%Y-%m-%d')) as Days " & _
                   "from " & _
                        "jo_hdr as a " & _
                             "inner join " & _
                        "branch as b ON a.BRNCH_CODE = b.BRNCH_CODE " & _
                             "inner join " & _
                        "dr_hdr as c ON c.TRAN_REF = a.TRAN_NO " & _
                             "inner join " & _
                        "dr_det as d ON d.DR_NO = c.DR_NO " & _
                   "where " & _
                        "c.DEL_DATE BETWEEN '" & dtpSDate.Text & "' AND '" & dtpEDate.Text & "' " & _
                             "and a.LABEL_CODE = '" & FtMK_Code & "' " & _
                             "and a.BRNCH_CODE = '" & chkBranch & "' " & _
                             "and SUBSTRING(d.REG_PRI,LENGTH(d.REG_PRI) - 1,2) = 75 " & _
                             "and SUBSTRING(d.REG_PRI,LENGTH(d.XL_PRI) - 1,2) = 75 "

            cmd = New MySqlCommand(strQ, con)
            da = New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            ds = New DataSet
            da.Fill(ds, "tblJO")

            For r = 0 To ds.Tables("tblJO").Rows.Count - 1
                Application.DoEvents()
                colItemCode = ds.Tables("tblJO").Rows(r)(0).ToString
                colDel_Date = ds.Tables("tblJO").Rows(r)(1).ToString
                colReg_pri = ds.Tables("tblJO").Rows(r)(2).ToString
                colXL_pri = ds.Tables("tblJO").Rows(r)(3).ToString
                colLabel = ds.Tables("tblJO").Rows(r)(4).ToString

                sumStyle = ds.Tables("tblJO").Rows(r)(5).ToString
                sumJO = ds.Tables("tblJO").Rows(r)(6).ToString
                sumNo = ds.Tables("tblJO").Rows(r)(7).ToString
                colDays = ds.Tables("tblJO").Rows(r)(8).ToString

                'for the number to decimal
                colReg_pri = FormatNumber(colReg_pri, 2)
                colXL_pri = FormatNumber(colXL_pri, 2)


                'get the total quantity and the branch quantity
                get_TotalQty_and_BranchQty()

                'if the branch quantity is zero
                If branchQty = 0 Then
                    PCT = "N\A"

                Else
                    'compute the percent sold
                    PCT = totalQty

                End If

                dvList.Rows.Add(False, colItemCode, PCT, colDel_Date, Format(Date.Now, "yyyy-MM-dd"), colDays, _
                                colReg_Pri, colXL_Pri, colLabel, "JO", dtpSDate.Text, dtpEDate.Text, _
                                clbBranch.CheckedItems(i).ToString, mkType)
            Next

        Next

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        con.Close()
    End Try

End Sub
```

I have use indexes in my tables, and also add application.doevents. Is there anything I could do to make the populating in the datagridview faster with this code? I'm trying to search about making the datagridview doublebuffered because I read it online that I will make the datagridview faster but I have no idea how to use it.

Any help will be appreciated, Thank you.

Comment: It seems like you need to take a look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181777/use-of-application-doevents Regarding doing it faster, I don't think that there are many ways to speed this code up. What you, most likely, want is the population of the DGV to not interfere with the GUI (and thus don't get your form frozen); in that case, you should rely on backgroundworker (retrieve the data from the DB in the back thread, store it into a DataTable, for example, and, once all this is done transfer it to the DGV, via DataSource or adding row by row).

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is using

```
Application.DoEvents
```

I'm not going to get into the details of why this is bad practice, try using a Background Worker instead.

Comment: ok sir I will search about the background worker, thank you :)